# Google App Engine Angular + Express always 404 on refresh

Tags: angular, express, google-app-engine

I have an angular and expressJS app on Google app engine, every time I refresh I get hit with a 404 error page. I see people solve this issue by using handlers in their app.yaml file but any attempt at doing this breaks my app - has anyone had to do this before when Express is service the Angular files ?

Project folder structure on GAE
./build ExpressJS backend logic
./public Angular 9 frontend (prod build)

My Express Server is the following

...

```
    const app = express()
    app.set('views', 'cloud/views')  // Specify the folder to find templates
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')    // Set the template engine
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));

    app.use('/backend', api)

    // Serve static assets from the /public folder
    app.use('/', express.static('./public'))
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue with my angular app served by express from feathersjs.
Adding something like this might fix it:

```
app.use('/', express.static('./public', { redirect: false }));
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join('./public', 'index.html'));
});
```